# Assign constant value to variable python called a server function firestore.SERVER.TIMESTAMP

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to assign the same timestamp to a few fields in Firestore. I am using python 3.7

My code to generate the timestamp is this.

```
current_system_timestamp    = firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP
```

I am using the current_system_timestamp to update fields in Firestore. Like this.

```
   channel_id_doc_ref.set({
                    'timestamp'  : current_system_timestamp,
                    'initiator_name'       : user_name
                })

 notes_doc_ref.set({
            'note'         : chat_note
            'timestamp_entered'     : current_system_timestamp
        })
```

Unfortunately the two timestamp values after they are set in Firestore is different - by miliseconds. This leads me to believe that I need to declare current_system_timestamp as a constant in python. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

`firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP` gets it final value on Firestore servers, after the request is sent.  The value isn't known on the client at the time the document is written.  Since your client code is writing two different documents at two different times, you can expect the final timestamps to be different, as they will not both hit the server at the exact same moment in time.

Assigning `firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP` won't change anything.  If you require that two documents have the same timestamp, you will have to write special code to do so.  What you can do instead is write the first document, then immediately read it back, capture the final timestamp out of it, then use that as the timestamp field in future documents.